# when clicked button rotates and give image

Tags: android, button, android-animation

I want to create an app in which i require that a customised button when clicked, rotates and an image appears from behind it..
please note that i'm a beginner so don't use very technical language..

thanks in advance

[EDIT] please tell how i should design the xml as well..
till now i have created a custom button..so should i make an image view behind it or in front of it..

[CODE ADDED]

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,90);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
button1.startAnimation(rotate);

AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
alpha.setFillAfter(true);
image.startAnimation(alpha);
}});

image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
alpha.setFillAfter(true);
image.startAnimation(alpha);

RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(90,0);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
button1.startAnimation(rotate);
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a technical language you would need to load an Animation or just instantiate one on the OnClickListener for the button and change also animate the image alpha from 0 to 1.

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,90);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
RotateAnimation rotateBack = new RotateAnimation(90,0);
rotateBack.setFillAfter(true);
AlphaAnimation alphaShow = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
alpha.setFillAfter(true);
AlphaAnimation alphaHide = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
alpha.setFillAfter(true);  

button.onClick = {
   button.startAnimation(rotate);
   image.startAnimation(alphaShow);
}

image.onClick = {
   image.startAnimation(alphaHide);
   button.startAnimation(rotateBack);
}
```

Comment: "image" used here is referring to an imageView??

Comment: yeah. Most android UI implements startAnimation

Comment: Just make sure the image android:alpha is set to 0.0 on the layout.

Comment: i am having an issue while using it..actually i want that when i click on the button, it rotates and an image appears from behind it..and when i click on that image, it rotates and the button appears again..and this continues again n again..

Comment: now i have implemented the button click and image click but this thing i'm not able to repeat again and again.

Comment: I would create the 4 animations (rotate, rotateBack, show, hide) and then use them as you wish. If the button is clicked I apply rotate and show, if the image is clicked I apply the rotateBack and the hide animations.

Comment: i implemented what u said..but the issue is just that when i reclick the button, it doesn't show the image back..i'm adding the code above i have used..

Comment: now once i click the button, i get the image..then if i click the image, i get the button..but now when i re-click the button i dun get the image back..

Comment: try using clearAnimation() on both the button and the view. check this for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: no problem. don't forget to approve the answer and vote it up. glad I could help.